# More Like This query on child documents

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

I'm trying to get similar documents in Elasticsearch using the More Like This query. I had a working solution for a while, but since then the document structure has changed and we now have a parent to each document. I can't find anything indicating child documents cannot be found using MLT but that's what it seems like. Can anybody shed some light on why this wouldn't work?

**I'm not getting an error, but just zero documents in the result**

**Types**

```
car: {
  _parent: {
    type: "dealer"
  },
  _routing: {
    required: true
  },
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: "string"
    },
    make: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    model: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    modelGroup: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    modelRaw: {
      type: "string",
      analyzer: "model_raw_analyzer"
    },

    fuel: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    gearbox: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    additionalVehicleData: {
      properties: {
        bodyType: {
          type: "string"
        },
        color: {
          type: "string"
        },
        colorGroup: {
          type: "string"
        },
        cylinderVolumeCC: {
          type: "long"
        },
        engineEffectHp: {
          type: "long"
        },
        engineEffectKw: {
          type: "long"
        },
        enviromentClass: {
          type: "string"
        },
        fourWheelDrive: {
          type: "boolean"
        },
        fuels: {
          properties: {
            co2Emissions: {
              type: "double"
            },
            engineEffectKw: {
              type: "long"
            },
            name: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        },
        height: {
          type: "long"
        },
        length: {
          type: "long"
        },
        make: {
          type: "string"
        },
        maxSpeed: {
          type: "string"
        },
        noPassangers: {
          type: "long"
        },
        weight: {
          type: "long"
        },
        width: {
          type: "long"
        }
      }
    },
    bodyType: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    equipment: {
      type: "string",
      index_analyzer: "swedish_edge_ngram",
      search_analyzer: "swedish"
    },
    freetextColor: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
    /*** MORE PROPERTIES HERE ... ***/
  }
}
dealer: {
  properties: {
   id: {
      type: "string"
    },
    name: {
      type: "string",
      fields: {
        raw: {
          type: "string",
          index: "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
    /*** MORE PROPERTIES HERE ... ***/
  }
}
```

My query that worked earlier was as simple as below to my main index and on the type `car`, where the ID `8379511` is a valid car ID:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "ids": ["8348446"],
      "min_term_freq":1,
      "min_doc_freq":1
      }
  }
}
```

Altering the query to be use "like_text" instead of "ids" like this works, but isn't really what I'm after as I wanted the logic for finding search result based on more parameters of the `car`:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "like_text": "volvo",
      "min_term_freq":1,
      "min_doc_freq":1
      }
  }
}
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: By any change, did you disable the _all field? You're not specifying any field You can also play with the min_term_freq and min_doc_freq, but I think those parameters are already the lowest possible so...